Returning a wchar_t* from a DLL function not working?
Need some help to figure out why I can't get the expected result back from a call to this dll function below. The external dll function is called from within an executable and it returns a garbled result. Something is being sent back if I get a garbled string right?
// calling code

const wchar_t *symptr = expFunc8(id);

printf("%s\n", symptr); // prints this garbled string 0·o_²⌂

// dll function

EXPFUNC const wchar_t* __stdcall expFunc8(const unsigned int id) {

    wchar_t symbuf[BUFFER_128];

    memset(symbuf, 0x00, BUFFER_128);

    swprintf_s(symbuf, BUFFER_128 - 1, L"%s", symM[id]->name); // name is char[]

    const wchar_t *symptr = &symbuf[0];

    printf("%s\n", symptr); // prints expected result so ptr is fine

    return symptr;
}

If I pass in a buffer pointer it works but is it possible return a pointer instead or this is the only way to do it?
EXPFUNC void __stdcall expFunc8(const unsigned int id, wchar_t *buf) {

    swprintf_s(buf, BUFFER_128 - 1, L"%s", symM[id]->name);
}

TIA

You return a pointer to a local variable, a variable whose life will end when the function returns. That means the pointer will become immediately invalid. I recommend you pass in a pointer to the buffer (and its size) as arguments to the function, and it fills that buffer.

@defa0009 Pass in a pointer to a buffer that the caller owns - then fill in the buffer in the dll. Pointers are not what they point to. You don't assign to the (copy of) the pointer in the dll, you put stuff in the buffer it points to.

@Avi Berger that works but is it possible to not have to pass in a pointer and return a pointer instead?

@defa0009 even if you return a pointer that's valid, there will be no way for you to free the pointer when you're done with it.  The DLL and main app may be using completely different heaps.

The pointer isn't the issue. The buffer is. If you return a pointer, what is it pointing to? If it is a buffer that is a local variable of the function called, then the buffer is no longer valid or usable when the function returns. You could dynamically allocate (malloc) a buffer in the dll, but then you are responsible for freeing that buffer when you are done with it. To do that you will need another function in the dll to call to properly free the buffer.

Once again: "Pointers are not what they point to." The issue is not in returning a point, but what the pointer is  pointing to. If it is pointing to something that no longer formally exists, attempting to dereference it is undefined behavior. "return a pointer instead" would be fine if it pointed to something that would continue to exist. So far you don't have such a thing. A house doesn't continue to exist after a demolition team has had its way with it, even if its address is still written on some envelope.

Perhaps you are thinking of a different language like Java or C#. Unlike references in those languages, pointers don't maintain the lifetime of what they refer to.

printf("%s\n", symptr); is invalid. It should probably be wprintf("%ls\n", symptr); since you are dealing with wide chars. ( or possibly printf("%ls\n", symptr); )

Thanks for all the help... sounds like passing in the buffer is the safest solution.

There are two ways to get a string from a function in C:
Method 1. Calling code creates a buffer and passes it to the function. Function writes result to the buffer. The function can be void.
Method 2. Function allocates a buffer using memory allocation function like malloc and returns the pointer to the buffer. Calling code is responsible to free the memory using free. This would work when memory is allocated in the DLL and deallocated in exe, as long as both EXE and DLL use the same version of C runtime library stdlib.
In addition to handling the memory correctly, you need to make sure you work consistently with single byte char type vs. "wide char" wchar_t strings. You may need to convert one type to another. Note using wprintf and L"..." for wide string literals.
Also, when you work with memory functions like memset and wide char strings, remember to distinguish between memory size in bytes and string length in wide characters. Note passing length*sizeof(wchar_t) when initializing the buffer with memset.
Method 1.
Calling code
wchar_t clientBuffer[BUFFER_128];
expFunc8(id, clientBuffer, BUFFER_128);
wprintf(L"%s\n", clientBuffer); // should print correct string 

DLL function
EXPFUNC void __stdcall expFunc8(const unsigned int id, 
             wchar_t* symbuf, int bufferSize) 
{

   memset(symbuf, 0x00, bufferSize*sizeof(wchar_t));
   // Since name is char[] convert it to wide char
   // check if the name is longer than the buffer size
   // and handle the error
   int length = strlen(symM[id]->name);
   if (length >= bufferSize) 
       length = bufferSize - 1;

   mbstowcs(symbuf, symM[id]->name, length);
   wprintf(L"%s\n", symbuf); // prints expected result 
}

Method 2.
Calling code
wchar_t* functionAllocatedBuffer = expFunc8(id);
wprintf(L"%s\n", functionAllocatedBuffer); // should print correct string

// calling code has to free the memory allocated by the function
free(functionAllocatedBuffer);

DLL function
EXPFUNC wchar_t* __stdcall expFunc8(const unsigned int id) 
{
   // Since name is char[] convert it to wide char
   int length = strlen(symM[id]->name);
   size_t size = length*sizeof(wchar_t)
   wchar_t* symbuf = (wchar_t*)malloc(size); 
   memset(symbuf, 0x00, size);
   mbstowcs(symbuf, symM[id]->name, length);
   wprintf(L"%s\n", symbuf); // prints expected result 
   return symbuf;
}


Fair point Avi, I'll update my answer for C.

Thanks I will update my memset accordingly.
